# How to initialize and then update an object?

Tags: python, oop

I have a set of tasks, each task has an id, duration, successors and requirements.
I created the following class:

```py
class Task:
    
    def __init__(self, identif, process, suc, req):
        self.identif = id 
        self.duration = process
        self.successors = succ
        self.requirements = req
```

Then I will create a dictionary whose keys are ids and values are objects of type `Task` to load all my data present in the image.

I have the following questions:

1. When parsing the first line in the below image, I will first create a task  of duration 0, successors and requirements [0,0,0,0].
   For some reason, I will need to create **now** the task objects for  and . However, at this stage I don't know any information about those tasks so I need to find a way to create them using only their ids and come back later to update. How to do it?
2. The way I store my data: I have two choices. The first one is for each task, the successors are a list of id i.e a list of strings. The second one will be a list of objects of type `Task`. Which one is more efficient? (e.g. Is there "pointers" to the same object or Python is considering copies of the objects?) Which one is more "safe" (i.e inducing less errors)?

Comment: Accepting either task names or `Task` objects for the successors list seems like it would be a useful feature: you wouldn't have to create all your tasks in reverse chronological order.  The accessor/getter method for successors could automatically translate task names into actual `Task`s by looking them up in some registry.

Comment: @jasonharper what about the memory ? Is there an impact on considering the successors as `Task` objects?

Comment: There is no memory overhead, except for the underlying array in the list, for the list to contain `Task` objects that are also referred to somewhere else. Using strings would require *more* memory, potentially (unless maybe you intern all the strings).

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, just give defaults to your `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, id, duration=None, successors=None, requirements=None):
```

and then define an update method to set these. For the second, having a list of tasks is correct and efficient. List of strings is kludgy.

Comment: But how to avoid creating two copies of the same task in the list of tasks? How to find the appropriate task from the list to update it?

Comment: @PatrickK. I don't understand the question. You create one task for each id, so how can you create duplicates? I have no idea what triggers an update.

Comment: **In the first line**, I will create the task whose id is 'OR1T1' with all of its information. However, the task whose id 'OR1T2' will only be created based on its identifier. Thus at the end of parsing of this line my list that contains all the tasks will have a "full" task (the one whose id is "OR1T1") and a task that needs an update (the one whose id is "OR1T2"). **When passing to the second line**, I need to check if the task  is already in the list of tasks. If it's the case I need to update its information. Otherwise I will create a new object task and append it to my list.

Comment: @PatrickK. so, the correct solution is to create a dictionary of tasks, whose keys are the names, and the values are the task objects, and then for each new id, do `if id in mydict update(mydict[id]) else mydict[Id] = task(...)`

Comment: Given that a key of the dictionary is the id of a task and  a value is a Task object that already has an id attribute, Is this a redundancy?

Comment: @PatrickK. It depends on whether the id is used in any other part of the program, but it is a useful thing to have anyway - you don't know when you might want it, and you don't want to rewrite your program then. The amount of redundancy is tiny, so if it is efficiency you care about, don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216683/discussion-between-patrick-k-and-igor-rivin).